# Derived Equivalence of Sheaves and Homotopy

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, at.algebraic-topology

This question loosely elaborates on an [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66098/sheaves-with-isomorphic-cohomology-but-not-quasi-isomorphic). It is pretty silly, but I'd like to hear some authoritative answers.

Recall that if $f:S^{\bullet}\to T^{\bullet}$ is a quasi-isomorphism of sheaves over $X$, which is, say, a manifold, then for every open set $U\subset X$, we have an induced isomorphism $R\Gamma(U,S^{\bullet})\to R\Gamma(U,T^{\bullet})$, so $H^i(U,S^{\bullet})\cong H^i(U,T^{\bullet})$ and in particular $H^i(X,S^{\bullet})\cong H^i(X,T^{\bullet})$.

To what extent is the converse true? At the coarsest level, when does a canonical isomorphism $R\Gamma(X,S^{\bullet})\to R\Gamma(X,T^{\bullet})$ reflect an underlying derived equivalence?

For a counterexample to the coarsest case, I believe the following serves: Consider a space $X$. Consider the constant sheaf on $k_X$. Let $f:X\to x_0$ be the retraction to a point $x_0\in X$. By standard theorems, we know that $H^i(X,Rf_*k_X)\cong H^i(X,k_X)$, but evaluating $Rf_*k_X(U)$ on any open subset $U$ missing $x_0$ assigns zero, as the fiber is empty. So in general these sheaves are not derived equivalent. What if $X$ deformation retracts to $x_0$? Is $k_X$ and $Rf_*k_X$ derived equivalent then? What if the homotopy doesn't have some Vietoris-Begle type behavior? See Kashiwara Schapira 2.7.8.

Comment: A comment about terminology: usually "derived equivalence" refers to a triangulated equivalence between derived categories. I think what you are calling "derived equivalence" above is usually called "quasi-isomorphism" or just "isomorphism".

Comment: I realize that, but for someone who is more familiar with algebraic topology, where quasi-isomorphism refers to inducing isomorphisms on cohomology groups of a space, i.e. sheaf cohomology of the constant sheaf, then one is tempted to think that quasi-iso means a map inducing isomorphisms on sheaf cohomology and not cohomology sheaves (although the presheaf description of the latter is close to the former). I have to admit that although the definition was unambiguous, my semantic web conflated my intuition of the two. Thanks to Sam's answer, we now know when the two agree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are asking: when is the functor $R\Gamma$ conservative (in the derived sense - i.e. if $R\Gamma (f)$ is a quasi-isomorphism then $f$ is a quasi-isomorphism). This is equivalent to $R\Gamma$ having no kernel - i.e. if $R\Gamma (F) \cong 0$, then F $\cong 0$ (by taking cones).

If you restrict to the triangulated subcategory generated by the constant sheaf $k_X$, I claim that $R\Gamma$ is conservative. This category can be thought of as something like derived unipotent local systems on $X$. The Barr-Beck theorem says that it is equivalent to dg modules over the algebra $C^\ast (X)$ of cochains on $X$ (so it is still interesting even if $X$ is simply connected).

Proof of claim: Let $f : X \to pt$ be the projection, and $C$ a (complex of) sheaves on $X$ such that $R\Gamma (C) = Hom _X(k_X , C) \cong 0$. Then if $T$ is any element of the triangulated subcategory generated by $k_X$, $Hom_X (T,C) \cong 0$. In particular, if $R\Gamma (T) \cong 0$, then $Hom _X(T,T) \cong 0$, so $T\cong 0$.

I think that this should be the largest triangulated subcategory of sheaves on $X$ on which global sections are conservative, but I am not sure how to prove this in general. It would follow from the Barr-Beck theorem if we knew that $R\Gamma$ preserved geometric realizations of simplicial objects, for example.

This situation is reminiscent of quasi-coherent sheaves on an affine scheme - this category is generated by $\mathcal O_X = f^\ast k$, and is equivalent to modules over $\Gamma (\mathcal O_X)$.

*About your question*: if $X$ deformation retracts to a point, then are $k_X$ and $Rf_\ast k_X$ quasi-isomorphic? (where by $Rf_\ast k_X$ I assume you mean the corresponding skyscraper sheaf on $X$). Doesn't your argument just above work (provided $X$ is not a point)?

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thank you.